# Able to retrieve information from SOLR

Tags: java, eclipse, solr, web-crawler, solrj

I am new to nutch and solr(Only started learning Nutch & Solr on the start of Sept)and planning to do a simple web application using **java eclipse** with a search function. Pardon with my phrasing of question.

1)I will use Nutch to crawl some information from a blog and index it into Solr.

2)Then (this is the part that I have no idea how to start and I want to achieve) **I want to use my own search function and be able to search the information I indexed into SOLR.**

If I am not wrong I think I will need to use something call SolrJ. And I am working this on Ubuntu. Hope that any expert on Nutch and Solr will be able to guide me. Thank you very much! I am using **Solr 5.3.0**

Comment: Hi, please provide more details and maybe an example as it's not really clear what you're trying to achieve. Afterwards I can eventually provide the SolrJ code with more details.

Comment: @AR1   
As i am new to this. I don't really know how to phrase my question. But it is suppose to be like this. First I will crawl a blog using nutch and index it into SOLR. And after that I will code a simple web app using java eclipse with a searching function(Suppose to act like a search engine). And this is the part that I have no idea how to start. I want to use my search function and be able to search the stuff that I index to into SOLR, for instance retrieve the information that I indexed into SOLR. (This is what I want to achieve). And I am using SOLR 6.2.0

Answer (score 0):

That's correct, you need to use SolrJ.

> The SolrJ API is included with Solr, so you do not have to download or
>   install anything else. However, in order to build and run applications
>   that use SolrJ, you have to add some libraries to the classpath.

You can find both the list of libraries needed and code examples in the official wikis: [Solrj](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj) and [Using SolrJ](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Using+SolrJ). Moreover there is a useful example (even if a bit dated) also on the "Apache Solr Cookbook" recipe nr 8.4.
So, to answer your question, you need to create a new project in Eclipse and add the **solrJ** library as advised in the sources mentioned above. You'll find plenty of code examples in the sources so I won't include any in this answer. I hope this helps.